# Why #include<bits/stdc++.h> does not work by default on windows?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, header-files, preprocessor-directive

I have installed the mingw-w64 compiler on windows. But using #include<bits/stdc++.h> in the c++ program preprocessor directive always gives an error. How can this be fixed?

Comment: By not using that? [c++ - Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++, it doesn't have to exist.

Comment: *But using #include<bits/stdc++.h>* -- Where did you get the idea to use this header?  No good C++ book has this.  Or are you attempting to learn C++ from one of those "online competition coding" sites?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It is standard practice in the competitive (speed) programming world, including books about the same.  Gotta save those precious seconds of typing!

Comment: I can't wait till those sites go to C++ 17.  Then all of time saved typing that header will, in many cases, lead to compiler errors where the competitor is scratching their head as to the issue, thus wasting time.  Especially if they have any identifiers with the name of [data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data)

Comment: If you do want help with using this abomination please post a [mre] with the full error message and compiler version. You're often better off using visual studio's compiler on windows rather than mingw as it can be easier to install correctly

Comment: It doesn't **work** by default because it doesn't **exist** by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header file. Thus, it is not guaranteed to work except with certain specific compilers. Even different versions of the same compiler might or might not provide it.

When it is available, `bits/stdc++.h` just `#include`s every standard C++ header file. This might make sense for someone just starting out in the language, so they don't have to worry about figuring out which includes they need and which they don't. But using it slows down compile time, might in certain cases make the executable bigger than it needs to be, and (as you discovered) makes the code non-portable.

The only solution to this is to not use it, and instead, `#include` just the specific headers you need. You're really "supposed" to do it as you program; when you need a certain function declared in a header, you include that header, then write the function call. Some IDEs will tell you which includes you need for each function.

But if you've already gotten the code all written, you can cheat. Just delete the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` line and try to compile. If the compiler complains about missing or undefined symbols, google the symbol to figure out which header it comes from, and `#include` it. Rinse and repeat until you get a clean compile.

Comment: Following the steps in the last paragraph will get the code to compile, but the result is not necessarily portable. Standard library headers are allowed to define other symbols that aren't required for that header, so adding one header might fix some other missing symbols. When you move to a different compiler they'll be undefined, and you'll have to add more `#include` directives.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, things like that are why I called it a "cheat". But I don't think it would be too bad, since by that time the OP would know how to look up standard header files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VS Code can't find the <bits/stdc++.h>.
It is not included where the headers files are included. So we just have
to copy and paste the stdc++.h file to header files of vscode.
So go to your MinGw directory and search for stdc++.h.
open its file location. Now come back a little bit to the bits folder and copy it.
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32

We need to include this folder in the vs code header files.

Now go to Program Files(x86) open the Microsoft Visual Studio and navigate to this location
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include

Now paste your bin folder here. Refresh the visual studio code and it should work fine

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways to let a compiler or IDE know where to find system headers than copying the entire folder.

Comment: But this method works perfectly dude. For beginners like me it will be much easier

Comment: "Much easier" does not equate to "better". If you want to learn C++, then learn it ***properly***.